# How to prevent hover effect from disabling when going on dropdown in IE?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I made a simple website that reproduces the bug in IE11.

When I hover on the red tab, it shows the blue container. In the blue container, there is a dropdown. If I then click the dropdown and hover on the items, the blue container disappears but the dropdown menu still shows. I tried in chrome, and this bug does not happen there, just IE it seems. I want the blue container to still show while I even go on the dropdown and hover on those things.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tab {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hovermenu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: -ms-page;
  position: fixed;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container:hover .hovermenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">TAB</div>
  <div class="hovermenu">
    <select>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
      <option value="3">C</option>
      <option value="4">D</option>
      <option value="5">E</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to me that Chrome is the one that's bugged. I don't think having the mouse over a drop-down list should count as hovering over what's behind the list.

Comment: @apokryfos while that's true, I'd say it's a deviation from the spec to enhance functionality by the Chrome team

Comment: I don't understand, I would of thought chrome's behavior is more preferable, as it looks better. But in either case, I still wan't to figure out how to persist the background in IE.

Comment: Maybe not such a deviation after all... the hover persists in Chrome 51, Firefox 47 and Edge 13 so...

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix it a quick and dirty way for IE.

```
        $("select").bind('focus', {}, function (event) {
            $(this).closest(".hovermenu").css('display', 'block');
        }).bind('blur', {}, function (event) {
            $(this).closest(".hovermenu").css('display', '');
        });
```